# List categories order by Random

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-list-categories

I'm not good with PHP.

I use "Advanced Categories Widget" to list categories on Sidebar.

I used this plugin because it offers the ability to display images categories.

But I need to order categories by random.

I find this code on the plugin:

```
function advanced_categories_widget_html( $args = array() ) {
    $args = wp_parse_args( $args );
    $args['walker'] = new Walker_Advance_Category_Widget;
    $output = wp_list_categories( $args );
    if ( $output ) return $output;
}
```

and i Find another code on forum which displays correctly categories by random order:

[wp_list_categories](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/random-categories-for-wp_list_categories#post-1010156)

how I can exploit the second code to hack the first code to list my categories with random order?

The PHP file for the plugin: http://codepad.org/a3yU7Xny

Answer (score 0):

Just add the "hack" the function in the plugin file :

```
function advanced_categories_widget_html( $args = array() ) {
    $args = wp_parse_args( $args );
    $args['walker'] = new Walker_Advance_Category_Widget;
    $cats ='';
    $categories=get_categories();
    $rand_keys = array_rand($categories, 5); // 5 is the number of categories you want
    foreach ($rand_keys as $key) {
        $cats .= $categories[$key]->term_id .',';
    }
    $output = wp_list_categories($args.'&include='.$cats);        
    if ( $output ) return $output;
}
```

Or by a cleaner way, add in your functions.php file :

```
function random_advanced_categories_widget_html( $args = array() ) {
    $args = wp_parse_args( $args );
    $args['walker'] = new Walker_Advance_Category_Widget;
    $cats ='';
    $categories=get_categories();
    $rand_keys = array_rand($categories, 5); // 5 is the number of categories you want
    foreach ($rand_keys as $key) {
        $cats .= $categories[$key]->term_id .',';
    }
    $output = wp_list_categories($args.'&include='.$cats);        
    if ( $output ) return $output;
}
```

Comment: I added this code to plugin or to function.php but i not working, 

My web site is : http://sayarti16.markedia.info/ (First widget on the sidebar)

The is the file for the plugin : http://codepad.org/a3yU7Xny

Answer (score 0):

Accordion to the documentation on the [Advanced Categories Widget plugin you're using](http://codecanyon.net/item/advanced-categories-widget/422878) --  -- you can specify 'orderby' in your plugin settings. See [this screenshot](https://0.s3.envato.com/files/47678737/04_screenshot.png).

You should have a random or rand option in the drop down.

Can't confirm cuz it's a paid plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,

the function "order by" random is not available see the screenshot : http://postimg.org/image/4fbxh3cbp/

I wonder how can i hack the code .

Thanks